# Bamboo Index value for Sentinel-2 not rendering between -1 and +1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, ndvi, band, composite

I created a composite band using last 5 years i.e., 2023, 2022, 2021, 2020, 2019 Sentinel-2 image for NDVI map and SI (Soil Moisture Index) map preparation. Then I created Bamboo Index (BI) map
from the created NDVI map and SMI map as shown below:-

```
BI = (Float("NDVI_map") - Float("SI_map")) / (Float("NDVI_map") + Float("SI_map"))
```

But the BI map was rendered but the index value is obtained as shown below:-

[image]

I have this issue that the BI value needs to be rendered between -1 and 1 but the value obtained are not such as shown also in Magnitude component of the Layer properties as shown below different Bands such as Band1, Band2, Band3, Band4, Band5 can be selected and each Band gives different BI value. So; what is the true band value here and how band value be changed to -1 and +1?
Note:-

```
BI= (NDVI-SI)/(NDVI+SI)
Where:
NDVI = Normalized Difference Vegetation Index
SI = Soil Moisture Index
```

The formula to calculate SI and NDVI in Sentinel-2 is as given below: -

```
SI = ((Band 8) - (Band 12) / (Band 8) + (Band 12))
NDVI= (Band8-Band4)/(Band8+Band4).
```